# How do I suppress any error condition in a sql server login trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, error-handling, triggers

I have a sql server login trigger to audit logins.

I want to suppress any errors being returned from it, as an error prevents login.

How do I do that?

Here's my trigger code

```
CREATE TRIGGER [trigLogon_Audit]
ON ALL SERVER
FOR LOGON
AS
    BEGIN
        IF (IS_MEMBER('dbo') = 1) RETURN;
        INSERT INTO Tracking.dbo.Activity (moment, name) VALUES (GETDATE(), ORIGINAL_LOGIN());

    END; 
GO

ENABLE TRIGGER [trigLogon_Audit] ON ALL SERVER
GO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@gbn's answer wasn't quite enough; even if the exception is caught, logins will still fail.  Oddly enough, I found another answer by @gbn that makes clear the solution: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8696/114706.  So here is my way of ensuring that exceptions in the logon trigger don't cause all logins to fail.  It may be overkill, but since exceptions here can be really painful to deal with, I'd rather go too far than not far enough.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigLogon_Audit  
ON ALL SERVER
FOR LOGON  
AS  
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        --make sure that XACT_ABORT is off, or exceptions (even if caught), will cause all logins to fail.
        DECLARE @XACT_ABORT_WasOn BIT = 0
        IF (@@OPTIONS & 16384) = 16384
        BEGIN
            SET @XACT_ABORT_WasOn = 1
            SET XACT_ABORT OFF; --this prevents any failure from killing the login.
        END

        --Put whatever logic you were trying to execute here; if there's a RETURN statement, make sure that XACT_ABORT gets set back to its original state.
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
       --Do nothing
    END CATCH

    --set XACT_ABORT back to its original state.
    IF (@XACT_ABORT_WasOn = 1)
    BEGIN
        SET XACT_ABORT ON;
    END
END
```

Comment: Is there a way to catch the failed logon error in the logon trigger?

Comment: Well, presumably you could do something in the catch block with @@error or error_message(), but you'd need to be very careful.  Putting those values into a table, for example could fail in a lot of ways, and then you'd have errors reporting errors.  In my opinion, even having a logon trigger is a fairly big risk, but if you can't avoid it, you should make any processing that occurs later resilient to failures.  For what I'm doing, my logon trigger copies data to a memory optimized table, but the procs that rely on the data know how to handle it when the data is missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can have error handling code in a trigger but you cannot do much because
when an error happens in a trigger the batch is aborted (unless you raise
the error yourself using `RAISERROR`).

Two good articles on error handling by Erland Sommarskog:

http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html

http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-II.html

Comment: These articles are about SQL Server 2000. Is there any solution for SQL Server 2008? I cannot believe that such simple thing is impossible on modern programming language.

Answer (score 1):

You can swallow the error silently using try/catch

```
CREATE TRIGGER [trigLogon_Audit]
ON ALL SERVER
FOR LOGON
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN TRY
    IF (IS_MEMBER('dbo') = 1) RETURN;
    INSERT INTO Tracking.dbo.Activity (moment, name) VALUES (GETDATE(), ORIGINAL_LOGIN());
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   --Do nothing
END CATCH
GO
```

Comment: only problem with this is that if it reaches the catch block from a batch-abortion error, you're screwed. As a result, you would not be able to commit or perform any more updates within the transaction.

Comment: @zedo: it's a logon trigger What transaction?

Comment: This did not help me. Exception is not suppressed in catch block as it should in normal programming languages.